# Python is misinterpreting my list

Tags: python, tkinter

For some reason, Python keeps throwing a TCL error where it says 'Unknown colour' despite the fact that the list it is taking strings from has nothing to do with colours. Is there any reason for this?

```
#Add words to this list to include them in the game
words = ["Games","Development","Keyboard","Speed","Typer","Anything","Aplha","Zealous","Accurate","Basics","Shortcut","Purpose","Window","Counter","Fortress","Modification","Computer","Science","History","Football","Basketball","Solid","Phantom","Battlefield","Avdvanced","Warfare","Download","Upload","Antidisestablishmentarianism","Supercalifragilisticexpialidocious","Discomobobulation","Liberated","Assassin","Brotherhood","Revelation","Unity","Syndicate","Victory"]

def nextWord():
        global score
        entry.focus_set()
        if entry.get().lower() == words[1].lower():
            score += 1

        entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
        random.shuffle(words)
        label.config(fg=str(words[1]), text=str(words[0]))
        scoreLabel.config(text="Score: " + str(score))
```

And this is the new error:

```
ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required
```

Also, I know some/most of my code maybe incorrect and I'd like to know how to set a maximum amount of times to shuffle and display a string before printing the time it took them to advance through all of them in a label. (Secondary question, don't have to answer if you don't want to)
Thanks.

Comment: If you are getting an exception, post the stack trace, and identify which line is causing the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here but I've changed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're explicitly telling tkinter to use the word as the colour though; that's what `fg` does in the line `label.config(fg=str(words[1]),...)`.

Since it's not a colour, you shouldn't do that.

Comment: So is there something else I can use to fix it or just remove fg=str?

Comment: I don't understand what you were trying to do. Yes, obviously you should remove it if you don't want to set the colour.

Comment: I was trying to get random words from the list and display in a label and I've removed it but it throws a value error

Comment: As khelwood says, if you are getting an error, you should post it along with the full traceback.